# Oracle SQL nearest point computation is slow and non-linear

Tags: sql, oracle, geolocation, query-optimization, oracle-spatial

I have a query to compute distances from each node to the nearest place using Oracle Spartial.

```
select n.nodeid as n_node_id, n.geoloc.sdo_point.y as node_y, n.geoloc.sdo_point.x as node_x,
p.id as place_i, p.geoloc.sdo_point.y as sl_y, p.geoloc.sdo_point.x as sl_x,
sdo_nn_distance(1)  as straight_line_distance
from  mynode n,    myplace p
where
sdo_nn (p.GEOLOC, n.geoloc, 'Unit = MILE sdo_num_res = 1', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

Indexes were created using this query

```
  -- Create spartial index
  INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata
          VALUES ('mynode ', 'GEOLOC',
                  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
                    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, 0.0000005),
                    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90, 0.0000005)),  8307 );
  --Wait for query to complete and run       
    CREATE INDEX mynode_IX ON mynode (GEOLOC)
            INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX
            PARAMETERS ('SDO_INDX_DIMS=2')
```

Actual execution time seems to be O(n*sqrt(n)) and the query runs slowly. For 10K places and `n` nodes I get

1 K nodes : 1 sec
10 K nodes : 12 sec
100K nodes:  326 sec
1 M nodes  : 100000+ sec

1. Brute forcing 10K nodes*10K places require about 1000M floating point operations and should take less than a second. Instead it takes 12 sec.
2. Computation complexity should be at worst linear. Why does it cost O(n^(3/2))?

Is there a way to make this computation run faster in Oracle?